# JS Мониторинг за значением переменной online

Tags: javascript, отладка, мониторинг

У меня есть модем Интертелеком Huawei EC5321. Хочу настроить антенну. Проблема заключается в том, что он в веб-интерфейсе отображает "грубо" уровень сигнала - от 0-5 полос. Но я хочу видеть более точные значения.

При анализе той странице я обнаружил что уровень сигнала приходит в числовом виде по ajax и уже js преобразует его в "полосочки" (файл home.js, функция index_updateConnectionStatus внутри

```
 var currentStatus = G_MonitoringStatus.response;
...
 signal_strength = '0' + parseInt(currentStatus.SignalStrength / 20, 10).toString();
....
$('#status_img').css({
            background: 'url(../res/icon_signal_' + signal_strength + '.gif) 0 0 no-repeat'
        });
```

хотел добавить после этих строк, чтобы отображался уровень в виде подсказки,
 строку

```
$('#status_img').prop('title', currentStatus.SignalStrength);
```

но как её туда впихнуть - не знаю....
результаты мониторинга приходят с http://192.168.1.1/api/monitoring/status
пример

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<ConnectionStatus>901</ConnectionStatus>
<SignalStrength>60</SignalStrength>
<SignalIcon>3</SignalIcon>
<CurrentNetworkType>11</CurrentNetworkType>
<CurrentServiceDomain>255</CurrentServiceDomain>
<RoamingStatus>0</RoamingStatus>
<BatteryStatus>0</BatteryStatus>
<BatteryLevel>4</BatteryLevel>
<simlockStatus>0</simlockStatus>
<WanIPAddress>10.132.199.150</WanIPAddress>
<PrimaryDns>192.168.4.45</PrimaryDns>
<SecondaryDns>192.168.4.46</SecondaryDns>
<CurrentWifiUser>3</CurrentWifiUser>
<TotalWifiUser>8</TotalWifiUser>
<ServiceStatus>2</ServiceStatus>
<SimStatus>240</SimStatus>
<WifiStatus>1</WifiStatus>
<CurrentNetworkTypeEx>26</CurrentNetworkTypeEx>
<CurrentSysmode>2</CurrentSysmode>
<msisdn></msisdn>
<classify>DataCard</classify>
</response>
```

возможно сделать как-то постоянный  парсинг этого урла с отображением строки SignalStrength на экране?

Comment: В чём проблема-то? Обновляете `title` при каждом обновлении.

Comment: @Other - как минимум мне нужно этот title добавить - по умолчанию его там нет. Какой код вставить понимаю, а как внести в тот файл изменения - нет. При настройке антенны мне нужно чтобы эта цифра обновлялась в режиме реального времени и мне была видна, поэтому и возникла данная задача...